# Input .value returns undefined

Tags: jquery, html, css

The value of the input entered is returned as `undefined`. I already saw other questions like this, but nothing worked. Anyway, when I use my jQuery it always gives me `undefined`.

jQuery:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#Input').keypress(
    function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert( ">" + $("#Input").value );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
body{
 background-color: black;
 color: #00c600;
 font-family: VT323;
}
input{
 background-color: black;
 color: #00c600;
 font-family: VT323;
 border:none;
 width: 98%%;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;
 border: 2px black;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: absolute; 
 bottom: 17px;
}

input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
h1{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 50px;
}
h2{
 padding-left: 20px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #00c600;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
</style>

<body>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">
 </script>
<script src="jquery.js">
</script>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=VT323' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<h1>FUN TIME BETA 0.1 </h1>

<div id="Text" style="overflow:auto; width:100%; height:400px;">
<h2>>Welcome to Fun Time</h2>
<h2>>Press F11 to enter full screen</h2>

</div>

<h3 style="float:left;list-style-type: none; position: absolute; bottom: 5px;">></h3> 

<input name="Input" id="Input" type="text" autofocus> </input>
</body>
</html>
```

When I alert, `undefined`. Console log, `undefined`. Append, gives back an error(the error is irrelevant). I tried changing up the code many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`value` is a property of native DOM element and `$('#Input')` is a jQuery object and they don't have the `value` property thus the error.

Since you are executing the code in the event handler, Either `this.value` or `$(this).val()` can be used.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your code from

```
$("#Input").value
```

to

```
$("#Input").val()
```